# Calculating growth and retention rate with sql

Tags: google-bigquery, analytics, retention

So I wrote a query to calculate the retention, new and returning student growth rate. The code below returns a result similar to this.

```
Row  visit_month    student_type    numberofstd  growth 
1      2013          new                574       null
2      2014          new                220       -62%
3      2014        retained             442       245%
4      2015          new                199       -10%
5      2015        retained             533        21%
6      2016          new                214        8%
7      2016        retained             590        11%
8      2016        returning            1         -100%
```

Query I have tried.

```
with visit_log AS (
    SELECT studentid,
            cast(substr(session, 1, 4) as numeric) as visit_month,
    FROM abaresult
    GROUP BY 1,
             2
    ORDER BY 1,
             2),
  time_lapse_2 AS (
        SELECT studentid,
               Visit_month,
               lag(visit_month, 1) over (partition BY studentid ORDER BY studentid, visit_month) lag
         FROM visit_log),
  time_diff_calculated_2 AS (
        SELECT studentid,
               visit_month,
               lag,
               visit_month - lag AS time_diff
         FROM time_lapse_2),

  student_categorized AS (
        SELECT studentid,
               visit_month,
               CASE
                        WHEN time_diff=1 THEN 'retained'
                        WHEN time_diff>1 THEN 'returning'
                        WHEN time_diff IS NULL THEN 'new'
               END AS student_type,
    FROM time_diff_calculated_2)

SELECT visit_month,
         student_type,
         Count(distinct studentid) as numberofstd,
         ROUND(100 * (COUNT(student_type) - LAG(COUNT(student_type), 1) OVER (ORDER BY student_type)) / LAG(COUNT(student_type), 1) OVER (ORDER BY student_type),0) || '%' AS growth
  FROM student_categorized
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

The query above calculates the retention, new and returning rate based on the figures of the last session student_type  category.

I am looking for a way to calculate these figures based on the total number of students in each visit_month and not from each category. Is there a way I can achieve this?

I am trying to get a table similar to this

```
Row  visit_month    student_type  totalstd  numberofstd  growth 
1      2013          new           574         574       null
2      2014          new           662         220       62%
3      2014        retained        662         442       22%
4      2015          new           732         199       10%
5      2015        retained        732         533       21%
6      2016          new           804         214       8%
7      2016        retained        804         590       11%
8      2016        returning       804         1         100%
```

Note:

The totalstd is the total number of student in each session and is gotten by new+retention+returning.

The growth calculation was assumed.

Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not have your source data, I am relying myself in the query you shared and the output results.

I created some extra code in order to output the desired result. I would like to point that I did not have access to BigQuery's compilation because I did not have the data. Thus, I have tried to prevent any possible errors the query myself. In addition, the queries between `**` are unchanged and were copied from your code. Below is the code (it is a mix of yours and the extra bits I created):

```
#*****************************************************************
with visit_log AS (
    SELECT studentid,
            cast(substr(session, 1, 4) as numeric) as visit_month,
    FROM abaresult
    GROUP BY 1,
             2
    ORDER BY 1,
             2),
  time_lapse_2 AS (
        SELECT studentid,
               Visit_month,
               lag(visit_month, 1) over (partition BY studentid ORDER BY studentid, visit_month) lag
         FROM visit_log),
  time_diff_calculated_2 AS (
        SELECT studentid,
               visit_month,
               lag,
               visit_month - lag AS time_diff
         FROM time_lapse_2),

  student_categorized AS (
        SELECT studentid,
               visit_month,
               CASE
                        WHEN time_diff=1 THEN 'retained'
                        WHEN time_diff>1 THEN 'returning'
                        WHEN time_diff IS NULL THEN 'new'
               END AS student_type,
    FROM time_diff_calculated_2)
#**************************************************************

#Code I added
#each unique visit_month will have its count
WITH total_stud AS (
SELECT visit_month, count(distinct studentid) as totalstd FROM visit_log 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY visit_month
),

#After you have your student_categorized temp table, create another one
#It will have the count of the number of students per visit_month per student_type
number_std_monthType AS (
SELECT visit_month,student_type, Count(distinct studentid) as numberofstd from student_categorized
GROUP BY 1, 2
),

#You will have one row per combination of visit_month and student_type
student_categorized2 AS(
SELECT DISTINCT visit_month,student_type FROM student_categorized2 
GROUP BY 1,2
),

#before calculation, create the table with all the necessary data
#you have the desired table without the growth
#notice that I used two keys to join t1 and t3 so the results are correct
final_t AS (
SELECT t1.visit_month, 
       t1.student_type, 
       t2.totalstd as totalstd, 
       t3.numberofstd 
FROM student_categorized2 t1 
       LEFT JOIN total_stud AS t2 ON t1.visit_month = t2.visit_month
       LEFT JOIN number_std_monthType t3 ON (t1.visit_month = t3.visit_month and t1.student_type = t3.student_type)
ORDER BY
)

#Now all the necessary values to calculate growth are in the temp table final_t
SELECT visit_month, student_type, totalstd, numberofstd,
       ROUND(100 * (totalstd - LAG(totalstd) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_month ORDER BY visit_month ASC) /LAG(totalstd) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_month ORDER BY visit_month ASC) || '%' AS growth
FROM final_t
```

Notice that I used [LEFT JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left_outer_join) in order to have the proper counts in the final table, once each count was calculated in a different *temp table*. Also, I did not use your final `SELECT` statement.

If you have any issues with the code, do not hesitate to ask.